# Android - getting the R.raw.value of a file based on filename?

Tags: java, android, string, file

I have a file in the res/raw folder called "book1tabs.txt", but in general I will not know what it is called. Then I have to do something like follows:

```
InputStream in = this.mCtx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.book1tabs);
```

But I want to use a string variable, like

```
String param = "book1tabs";
```

And be able to open up that same input stream.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
String param = "book1tabs";

InputStream in = this.mCtx.getResources().openRawResource(mCtx.getResources().getIdentifier(param,"raw", mCtx.getPackageName()));
```

`getIdentifier()` will return the id from `R.java` of particular parameter you passed.

Exactly what it will do is as follow

- Maps the Package Name
- Navigate to typeDef you provided
- Finds the resource name you provided in the typeDef

For more information http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html

Comment: Wow that line was quite a mouthful... But hey if it does the job, awesome. Will test it out.

Answer (score 2):

I find this method to be very useful to pull all sorts of resources by their string names...

```
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static int getResourceId(String name,  Class resType){

    try {
        Class res = null;
        if(resType == R.drawable.class)
            res = R.drawable.class;
        if(resType == R.id.class)
            res = R.id.class;
        if(resType == R.string.class)
            res = R.string.class;
                    if(resType == R.raw.class)
            res = R.raw.class;
        Field field = res.getField(name);
        int retId = field.getInt(null);
        return retId;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
       // Log.d(TAG, "Failure to get drawable id.", e);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will return the numeric id (assuming such a resource exists).  For the Class pass in `R.drawable` and for the string whatever it's xml based ID name is.

I always have this method hanging around all my projects for easy access.